# MySQL select query slow despite having indexes

Tags: mysql, query-performance, select

Have this rather simple SELECT on just one table:

```
SELECT id AS price_id
FROM prices
WHERE product_id IS NOT NULL AND product_id > 1
AND search_name_updated IS NULL
LIMIT 1000
```

For some reason, the query takes 10+ seconds to run.

The `prices` table have a bit more than 6 million rows and there are indexes on both the `product_id` column and the `search_name_updated` column.

If I drop one of the where clauses, like below, the query takes less than 0.1 seconds to run.

```
SELECT pri.id AS price_id
FROM wp_wbx_fh_product_prices pri
WHERE product_id IS NOT NULL AND product_id > 1
LIMIT 1000
```

Same great execution time if I cut it like below, i.e. the `search_name_updated` column alone isn't the problem.

```
SELECT pri.id AS price_id
FROM wp_wbx_fh_product_prices pri
WHERE search_name_updated IS NULL
LIMIT 1000
```

Any ideas for why the original query with all 3 where clauses is so slow?

I don't get it since there are indexes on both columns used in the where clause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `INDEX(search_name_updated, product_id)`  *in this order*
- A `LIMIT` without an `ORDER BY` gives you an unpredictable set of rows.  If you have the above composite index and add `ORDER BY product_id`, the query will still be efficient.  Almost any other combination will lead to a further slowdown.
- Get rid of `product_id IS NOT NULL AND` (as Liva suggests).  It is unnecessary since `> 1` implies that.  (The Optimizer may not be smart enough to optimize it out.)  `IS NULL` is similar to `=` when it comes to the Optimizer.

When building a composite (multi-column) `INDEX`, start with columns that are tested with `=` or `IS NULL`.  More: [*Index Cookbook*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql)

To further explain your experiments:

- The `PRIMARY KEY` (presumably just `id`) is tacked onto the end of each secondary key -- so it can reach over into the data's BTree for any other columns that are needed.
- A "covering" index is one that contains all the columns used anywhere in the `SELECT`.  This is faster because there is not the bouncing back and forth (1000 times or 8M times).
- Your original query involved 3 columns: One explicitly in the `INDEX`, `id`, and a third column.  So it was not "covering".
- Your other tests involved only 2 columns and the indexes you tried were "covering".
- The index I recommend is a "covering" index since it contains the 3 columns in your query.

Summary:  With `INDEX(search_name_updated, product_id)`

```
SELECT id AS price_id
    FROM prices
    WHERE product_id > 1
      AND search_name_updated IS NULL
    LIMIT 1000
```

(The order of `WHERE` clauses does not matter; the order of columns in the `INDEX` *does* matter.)

The execution will go something like

1. Drill into the index's B+Tree to find the first entry for `search_name_updated IS NULL` and `product_id > 1` and find an `id` there.
2. Deliver that `id`.
3. Move to the next `INDEX` entry and deliver that `id`
4. Repeat step 3 until there are no more rows satisfy the `WHERE`, or the `LIMIT 1000` has been reached.

Total:  1000 rows read from just the index's BTree.

All other formulations involve either a table scan a sort or bouncing between the two BTrees.

If you had

```
SELECT *
    FROM prices
    WHERE product_id > 1
      AND search_name_updated IS NULL
    LIMIT 1000
```

The execution would be similar, except that the index is no longer "covering".  Still, it will be reasonably fast -- because it hits *only* 1000 rows in the index BTree and *only* 1000 rows in the data BTree.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation. I understand things much better now.

Answer (score 1):

1. I suggest that you create an index on both columns together , put the product_id first. The optimizer usually picks only one index for WHERE condition.
2. you can get rid of the condition "product_id IS NOT NULL", as soon as you filter it by value NULL are out

Comment: When making a composite index, pick `=` tests first.  If you put `product_id` first, it won't use the other column.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Didn't know the optimizer usually only picked one index.